# Amazon S3 AccessDenied: Access Denied at Request.extractError - with active Object tagging

Tags: amazon-s3

We try to automate our S3 workflow by setting up a Lambda function to add custom tags to it.

Our Lambda functions fail with:

```
2019-11-04T11:32:40.057Z 41513606-8bdd-4c24-85c4-7773d213fc32 { AccessDenied: Access Denied
at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:585:35)
at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)
message: 'Access Denied',
code: 'AccessDenied',
region: null,
time: 2019-11-04T11:32:40.056Z,
requestId: '8F7360D2A816BF54',
extendedRequestId: 'yGXP21UJARJfGq7uz/Pr8JZiX0flImx3e11PL398cFae+S79rWp5dH7G9m2zmYAVysbFQvBChiI=',
cfId: undefined,
statusCode: 403,
retryable: false,
retryDelay: 25.314823366706207 }
```

We also seen a notice on the UI:

To enable replication of object tags IAM policies used for Cross-Region Replication must be updated if they were created prior to the introduction of Object tagging.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We ran into this `AccessDenied` error

we had to enable further policies for our IAM role:

```
"Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectTagging",
                "s3:PutObjectTagging",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
],
```

as you see there are specific policies for `GetObjectTagging` and `PutObjectTagging`